# Using Update statement to replace blanks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am using the below SQL update statement to replace all blank values with "Signature not required", but when I run it, I have the same amount of blanks as when I started. What am I doing wrong?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
UPDATE 
    shipments
SET 
    signature_required = REPLACE(signature_required,'','Signature not required')
WHERE 
    signature_required = ''
Commit Transaction;
```

Comment: ``NULL`` and ``BLANK`` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify the set statement by removing the 'Replace' function.  The values that are blank are located using the WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE 
shipments
SET 
signature_required = 'Signature not required'
WHERE 
signature_required = ''
```

This will only work if the values are actually stored as an empty string.

Comment: Plus 1 but I would trap and test for NULLS as well

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a space

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
UPDATE 
    shipments
SET 
    signature_required = REPLACE(signature_required,' ','Signature not required')
WHERE 
    signature_required = ' '
Commit Transaction;
```

or

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
UPDATE 
    shipments
SET 
    signature_required = REPLACE(isnull(Signature_required,' '),' ','Signature not required')
WHERE 
    ISNULL(signature_required,' ') = ' '
Commit Transaction;
```

Comment: for blank value, that not necessary, only string with leading space matters

Comment: blank and nulls are not the same. you can never assume that there is none.

Comment: again you can never assume.. NULLS work in mysterious ways

Comment: that's true bro

Answer (score 0):

If 'blank' means an empty string or `null` then using `coalesce()` to return an empty string for the comparison would work:

```
update shipments
set signature_required = 'signature not required'
where coalesce(signature_required,'') = '';
```

or using `or`

```
update shipments
set signature_required = 'signature not required'
where signature_required = ''
   or signature_required is null
```